# THEOS/iPhone Jailbreaking programming - How should I hide a View from the ViewController?

Tags: jailbreak, cydia, theos

I'm trying to program a Cydia's tweak and should hook a viewcontroller class while loading and hide the view - i've tried the following:

Tweak.xm:

```
%hook ScoresViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)fp8 {
    %orig;

    self.view.hidden = YES;
}

%end
```

but unfortunately, when trying to "make" the Tweak using THEOS , i get the following:

```
Making all for tweak scoresenhancer...
Preprocessing Tweak.xm...
Compiling Tweak.xm...
Tweak.xm: In function 'void       _logos_method$_ungrouped$ScoresViewController$viewWillAppear$(ScoresViewController*, objc_selector*, BOOL)':
Tweak.xm:49: error: request for member 'view' in 'self', which is of non-class type 'ScoresViewController*'
Tweak.xm: In function 'void _logos_method$_ungrouped$ScoresViewController$viewWillAppear$(ScoresViewController*, objc_selector*, BOOL)':
Tweak.xm:49: error: request for member 'view' in 'self', which is of non-class type 'ScoresViewController*'
lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/tmp//ccFsVzMR.out
make[2]: *** [obj/Tweak.xm.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
make: *** [scoresenhancer.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
```

I will appreciate your assistance.
I will also would like to understand how can I reach ivars of the customized class (i.e: ScoresViewController).

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing there telling the compiler that ScoresViewController is a UIViewController descendant. There are a couple things you could do here.

```
[(UIViewController *)self view].hidden = YES;
```

or

```
@interface ScoresViewController : UIViewController @end
...
self.view.hidden = YES;
```